# how to databind to ionClick in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to pass value of star rating through ionclick option, but I cannot pass value for it through ngModel. How can I can pass value when click ionclick?

```
 <ion-rating   (ionClick)="log($event)"  [(ngModel)]="rating" name="rating"></ion-rating>

 let service = {
    "serviceCenter":value.serviceCenter,
    "serviceType":value.serviceType,
    "date":value.date,
    "time":value.time,
    "rating":value.rating,
    "extraDetails":value.extraDetails,
    "review":value.review
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `(ionChange)` instead of `(ionclick)` and just pass your value in it